# Sharing "Allow Editing" grayed out

Tags: sharepoint-online, share, external-users

The "Allow Editing" setting is grayed out on the Share dialog for all files within a document library.

Can someone please help me enable this?

[image: Share Link Settings]

This setting can be checked under other document libraries.

Can Share settings be restricted per document library?

Comment: You mean that just the one document library has this issue in a site collection, is it right? What permissions does your account have on the library? Please test using a site collection administrator to check if there is any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having Office 365 support on the phone for 1.5 hours, they concluded that this setting is disabled for a document library when you enable "require check out" under Versioning Settings.

[image: Require Check Out]

Comment: crazy fix but rather informative.